# Postgresql ERROR: relation "tablename" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql

I am getting the follow error when trying to execute a `select * from tablename` statement in postgresql. If I execute the same comment from a db GUI client (dbVisualizer), I am able to execute it succesfully. I am using eclipse, java 8 and postgresql 10.

> ```
> ERROR: relation "tablename" does not exist
>   Position: 15
> ```

Comment: Is `tablename` really the table name? I'd say you're probably using mixed case and quoting in one place but not another, or you're connected to a different database

Comment: what you mean you try to execute it in postgresql?..

Comment: tablename is just a fake name a posted randomly on the question. I already validated the mixed case and quoting option and got no success result.

Comment: I mean I run the query against postgres db

Comment: One additional consideration is that I am using a MAC (macOS)

Comment: I found the root cause of the problem. I was actually creating the table in other db which was not the target of the SQL command